# How to combine line and bordered point into 1 legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot2::ggplot(data.frame("Year" = 2013:2022, "Value" = rnorm(10)), 
       aes(Year, Value, color = "Name with Spaces", fill = "Name with Spaces")) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(color = "blue", pch = 21) +
  scale_color_manual(values = "red") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = "yellow")
```

My code above will show the following plot in R

[image: ggplot image]

How can I put the two legend items into one, that is "a red line pass beneath the blue-bordered yellow point"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use identical `name` and `labels` values for both color and fill scales.

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot2::ggplot(data.frame("Year" = 2013:2022, "Value" = rnorm(10)),
                aes(Year, Value, color = "Name with Spaces", fill = "Name with Spaces")) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(color = "blue", pch=21, size = 2.25, stroke = 1) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "",
                     labels = "Name with Spaces",
                     values = "red") +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "",
                    labels = "Name with Spaces",
                    values = "yellow")
```

*Note*: You don't need to adjust the size and stroke in `geom_point`. I just wanted to show the colors better.

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to put the label in a column of your dataframe an map this column on the `color` and `fill` aes:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame("Year" = 2013:2022, "Value" = rnorm(10), color = "Name with Spaces")

ggplot(df, aes(Year, Value, color = color, fill = color)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(color = "blue", shape = 21, size = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(values = "red") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = "yellow")
```

[image]